# How can I assign to new values to static array in C?

Tags: c

Please advise me on how best to redeclare the array `fields` with new values using memcpy. If there's a better/optimum way to redeclare, please let me know that as well.

Here's my sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define array_size(array) sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])

struct user_profile {
    const char *first_name;
    const char *second_name;
    unsigned int age;
};

int main() {
    struct user_profile fields[] = {
        {"david", "hart", 32},
        {"billy", "cohen", 24},
    };
    
    for (int i = 0; i < array_size(fields); ++i) {
        printf("%s %s\n", fields[i].first_name, fields[i].second_name);
    }
    
    memcpy(fields, {{"zach", "roberts", 59}, {"mike", "fisher", 19}}, sizeof(fields));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your call of memcpy shall not compile in C because this record {{"zach", "roberts", 59}, {"mike", "fisher", 19}} is not an expression.

Comment: Could you please share how best to use memcpy in this scenario?

Comment: OT: It doesn't matter much but.... The title says "static array" but there isn't any static array in the code

Comment: I meant static array as in declaration/assignment that is not followed for dynamic array. I'm new to C, sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but you do not do this properly.

1. Using `memcpy`:

```
    memcpy(fields, (struct user_profile[]){{"zach", "roberts", 59}, {"mike", "fisher", 19}}, sizeof(fields));
```

2. You can simply assign structures:

```
    fields[0] = (struct user_profile){"zach", "roberts", 59};
    fields[1] = (struct user_profile){"mike", "fisher", 19};
```

Both methods use compound literals

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I was looking for it. And how about when length of the fields is more than 10, do I have to peform assignment seperately from fields[0]...fields[10]? What will be the best option out of both?